# Problemas para clicar em links/botões no IE usando VBA

Tags: html, vba, internet-explorer

Estou com um problema para automatizar o download de dados de um site usando o VBA. A primeira parte vai bem, o navegador entra na página desejada e insere os critérios em uma dropdown list. Só falta clicar no botão pesquisar, mas a macro para sem aparecer um debug nem nada.

```
For Each objLink In ie.document.getElementsByTagName("a")


    If objLink.href = ("javascript:void(0);") Then

          objLink.Click

          Exit For

        End If

    Next objLink


With ie
While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend





For i = 1 To 2
SendKeys "DEB"

'While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))

Next i

SendKeys "Negociações D"


While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend


''''' A partir daqui a macro não executa o código que faz rigorosamente a mesma coisa que o getElements antes do SendKeys. 

With ie


For Each objLink In ie.document.getElementsByTagName("a")


        If objLink.href = ("http://estatisticas.cetip.com.br/astec/series_v05/paginas/web_v04_10_03_consulta.asp") Then

              objLink.Click

              Exit For

            End If
Next objLink

End With



End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Você precisa realmente usar VBA para isso? Eu pergunto porque há muitos frameworks bons para esse tipo de automação (tipo Selenium, WatiN, Capybara, CasperJS) , principalmente para teste.

Answer (score -1):

Use a instrução `html.parentWindow.execScript (" comando click em java")`